how to track CPU utilization and memory utilization for Azure Webapp , function app
I'm trying to track webapps and function apps CPU % and memory % for azure managed grafana dashboard visuilizationbut unfortunately azure didnt offer individual webapp CPU% it only track CPU time and it gives CPU% on app service plan level as whole sum of all webapps and function apps , how can i get CPU% of webapps individually ?enter image description here
